# Cannot use nomath with stix

Tags: stix

I can't be the first person who has wanted to use `stix` with the `nomath` option, but it seems impossible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomath]{stix}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This produces

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 57.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.3 \begin
          {document}
```

Comment: And report the bug! (Information on page 3 of the manual.)

Comment: Apparently you *were* the first!

Comment: @cfr, thank you for the good advice.  Unfortunately I can't seem to get into my old SourceForge account.  Since DavidCarlisle (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232089/cannot-use-nomath-with-stix#comment549142_232092) already reported it, it shouldn't last long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in the package  right at the end there is the line

```
\def\stix@dotlessi{\ifmmode\imath\else\i}
```

which should say

```
\def\stix@dotlessi{\ifmmode\imath\else\i\fi}
```

Because of the interaction with the package option you can not really "patch" that with a redefinition, make a local copy and just edit the file.

Comment: Thanks for this, and for fixing the typo in my sample code.  (Is there any *really* easy way to C&P from an external file?  A literal C&P misses the four spaces at the beginning, so I was lazy and just re-typed, obviously incorrectly.)

Comment: @LSpice highlight the code with mouse then use the `{}` button in the editor (or type control-k) and the indent gets added,

Comment: @LSpice I pinged a representative of stipub about this, so I guess it will get fixed shortly.

Comment: I uploaded a new version of the package to CTAN which should fix this (in TeX Live 2015 at least).